# return non duplicates numbers in array from method

Tags: java

I am trying to remove duplicate numbers using method and return non-duplicate numbers, actually I am stuck in method right now.
this is my code :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class duplicateRemover{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[5];

    for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
      String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"PLEASE ENTER AN INTEGER:","INTEGERS",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
      array[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);

    }
    removeDuplicates(array);
   for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,array[i],"UNIQE INTEGERS",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
   }
     }
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int a []) {
   int []removedDup=new int[a.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i-1; j < a.length; j++){
      if (a[i] == a[i]) {
        removedDup[i] = j;
        break;

  }

 }
```

Comment: if (a[i] == a[i]) in removeDuplicates() looks like a problem

Comment: @TomMcIntyre provide an answer with the probably not-so-obvious problem in that line of code.

Comment: Unless your purpose is to learn, you could use a Set for this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Comment: @Simon I would say *especially* if the purpose is to learn... :-)

Comment: @Simon by the code above, OP's in learning phase and this is an exercise (note that he/she even uses plain arrays to handle the work and not `List`).

Comment: @Luiggi as you point out the OP is learning, this was a hint to point them in the right direction, not to do all their work for them.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I guessed that too, but it's also a good thing to learn to use standard libraries when possible.

Comment: @TomMcIntyre a hint can be turned into an answer by just providing the enough info and a proper explanation. I didn't mean you to reveal the whole solution for OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
    public static int[] removeDuplicates(int a[]) {
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n;) {
            if (a[j] == a[i]) {
                for (int k = j; k < n-1; k++)
                    a[k] = a[k + 1];
                n--;
            } else
                j++;
        }
    }

     int[] newArray = new int[n];
     System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, n);

     return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Won't it cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when `a[k] = a[k + 1];` and k=n-1?

Comment: thanks @Shreyos Adikari for your help but i got this error!!!! how to pass it  'at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)'

Comment: Thanks soooo much man it works properly now.. @ Shreyos Adikari

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand right that you want to get all the integers that occur only once?  This can be done easily with the collections API.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] a) {
    Set<Integer> unique = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (!unique.add(a[i]))
            results.add(a[i]);
    }
    int[] ret = new int[results.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        ret[i] = results.get(i);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously you're trying to multi loop element and compare it with others so if duplicate of that element exists you remove it and flag its index. this code you've written is buggy however I see your main problem now is that you compare element  to it's very own
I see `if (a[i] == a[i])` to be `if (a[i] == a[j])` then your code supposed to work or throw index out of bound exception

Comment: Without a proper explanation, this should be just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your array for each value and compare it with each other (you should have a nested "for"), then keep a list with duplicates' indexes, instantiate an array of size a.length-listOfDuplicateIndexes.size()......fill this array with a[] components whose indexes are not int ListOfDuplicateIndexes